# Dynamically created Html table disappearing after click event in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am creating dynamic html table using javascript ajax function. It will disappear after postback. I want retain those value even after page load.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can learn more about [ask] a question to better support the folks who can help you with your question.  Thanks!

Comment: You cannot. Items created with ajax are not persisted on PostBack. You will have to call the ajax function again.

Comment: @VDWWD, I'm pretty sure OP is trying to ask "How would I persist dynamically loaded Html after a page load". In which case, your comment is very misleading.

Comment: @AbdulG, I somewhat agree with you. My point was that you have to take some action to show the values again after postback. ViewState will not retain them. There are indeed more than one solution than the initial ajax load. So we are both right ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `HTML sessionStorage`. A simple example would look like this:

Save before your postback:

```
let tableData = $('#tableId').html();
sessionStorage.setItem("table", tableData);
```

Retrieve after page load:

```
let tableData = sessionStorage.getItem("table");
$('#tableId').html(tableData);
```

Bare in mind, you will need to put together some form of cache control as `sessionStorage` data will persist across page loads for your entire session.

You can also use `localStorage` object, in which case your data will not be lost after the session expires.